# Custom routes don't work with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

For example, my routes.rb looks like:

```
...
get 'abc/xyz' => 'abc#xyz', :as => 'abc_xyz'
...
```

application.js:

```
...
$('a').click(showSpinner);
function showSpinner(evt) {
    link = $(this);
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('body').append('<div class="spinner-overlay"></div>');
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = link.attr('href');
    }, 10);
});
...
```

When a link using that JavaScript goes to abc_xyz_path, it gives an ActiveRecord RecordNotFound error since it's looking for the abc record with id xyz instead of using the custom route. If I remove the setTimeout, however, there's no problem and it works. Does Rails' routing system have a problem with timeouts?

**UPDATE:**

I realized I didn't need the preventDefault() or setTimeout(), since this click handler would happen before the link redirected anyway. Problem solved.

Comment: 'link.attr('href');' is getting an href from somewhere. That href must be wrong - please past in the html snippet that it gets the href from, paste in the code that generates that html snippet, and also paste in the value you end up getting from 'link.attr('href')'.
Does it work if you simply click on the link manually?
Rails won't care at all about your timeout, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: It gets the href from the .html.erb file, like any other `link_to`. The JS gets called when I click the link (see my edits). When I remove the click handler, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I didn't need the preventDefault() or setTimeout(), since this click handler would happen before the link redirected anyway. No more problems.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your link works without javascript indicates that it's pointing to the correct URL. Rails won't know or care wether the request came after a javascript timeout or not, so that's not the issue.

So, the problem is that your line:

```
window.location = link.attr('href');
```

must be setting the wrong url. You should do:

```
console.log(link.attr('href'));
```

to check what it's getting, and update your question with that. I don't know what `link` is, but according to your code sample, it's not mentioned other than in the line `window.location = link.attr('href');`

What I'd be doing instead is:

```
window.location = $(this).attr('href');
```

`$(this)` will refer to the think that just received the click event, which is what you want.

Comment: link = $(this) (I updated the question accordingly). Sorry about that!

Comment: Before window.location = link.attr('href');, do a console.log(link.attr('href')); and then update your question with the output of that.